# How to check if Artisan::call is done and if true call a another function

Tags: php, laravel, command, laravel-artisan

so, I'm working on Laravel project

i build a Html form that control the `/config/app.php` file , so after the user click the submit button i call

`Artisan::call('config:cache')` to execute this changes

but this can take from **1.00 to 3:00 second** so i tried this :

```
//# if submit [in the method]:


Artisan::call('config:cache');
sleep(3); // to wait until generate the cache  
return Redirect::back()->with('status','every thing is updated!');
```

but what i need is to call the `Redirect::back()` right after  `Artisan::call` is done

example :

```
if (Artisan::call('config:cache')){
    return Redirect::back()->with('status','every thing is updated!')
}
```

Unfortunately the example did not work with me , its give me an empty white page **(not call `return`)**

what is the solution ? ,, Thanks in advance

Comment: Artisan:call should be synchronous, there should be no need to sleep.

Comment: @Devon If I do not call `sleep()` function its return to the page without change but after i add the `sleep()` its work very good but its take time